# File manager display error when opened with Explorer

Tags: filemanager

I met a quite strange problem, when I open the file manager directly, everything works well, but if I open it in an Explorer, for example, saving some downloaded file, the display of file manager will not be entire. Following are two examples

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Nautilus by using the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-share
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work ...

Comment: did you try removing gnome settings `sudo rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity`?